# AngularJS - error: [$rootscope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and am running into a problem.

I have a JSON array of invoices retrieved via a $http GET request that is being looped through here:

```
  <a ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" href="#" class="list-group-item">
    {{ invoice[data]["TxnDate"][0] }} -
    {{ invoice[data]["DocNumber"][0] }} - 
    ${{ invoice[data]["TotalAmt"][0] }} - 
    {{ getCustomer(invoice[data]["Id"][0]) }}

    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
    <i class="pull-right">Edit</i>
  </a>
```

The problem is that the array of invoices does not store any information about the customer except for the customer's reference number.

So, I created a function called `getCustomer` which queries my API for the customer's name by their reference number.

```
$scope.getCustomer = function(id) {

    var customer_id = id.match(/\d+/)[0];

    $http.post('/customers', customer_id).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

};
```

The problem is I am receiving this error:

```
error: [$rootscope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. aborting! watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Later, I will figure out a more efficient way to do this but I'm curious to know what is causing this error?

After doing some research, I think it has something to do with the fact that once the data in one of the list items changes, AngularJS needs to check all the list items.  Still, I'm very confused.  What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Where does invoices comes from? can you show that bit of your code?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah you should post some insight on your data structure (ie invoices). What does it look like. What is the "data" indexer?  Are u using a two level nested array for your invoices structure etc.

Comment: I just read your update. If you want to avoid this and only refresh your ng-repeat when an item is added or removed from the collection you can simply use the "track by" notation like so: `ng-repeat="invoice in invoices track by $index"`. See also the angularjs documentation for [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). The default implementation refreshes based on a computed $hash that changes each time any nested items' field is altered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to the use of a function inside a binding (interpolation {{}}). Due to its nature, angularjs constantly observes the $scope (view model) for changes. So if you are not careful you could bind to a function that always returns a new/different instance of an object. This triggers an infinite loop that angular identifies as an error and disables the binding in order to avoid stackoverflow. If say you changed your function to store the returned customer to a local variable you could avoid the problem.

Here is a complete snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  $scope.invoices = [
    { Id: "1", TxnDate: new Date(2014, 6, 26), DocNumber: "I001234", TotalAmt: 200.34 }, 
    { Id: "2", TxnDate: new Date(2014, 8, 2), DocNumber: "I000021", TotalAmt: 530.34 }, 
    { Id: "3", TxnDate: new Date(2014, 11, 15), DocNumber: "I000023", TotalAmt: 123 },  
    { Id: "4", TxnDate: new Date(2014, 12, 11), DocNumber: "I000027", TotalAmt: 5000 },  
  ];
  
  var testUrl = 'http://echo.jsontest.com/company/AKME/firstName/John/lastName/Doe';
  var _customerCache = {};
  $scope.customerCache = _customerCache;
  $scope.getCustomer = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // defer
    if (_customerCache[id])
        return deferred.resolve(_customerCache[id]);
    
    var customer_id = id.match(/\d+/)[0]; 

    $http.get(testUrl + customer_id + '/id/'+ customer_id).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        _customerCache[id] = response;
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="main"  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" ng-init="getCustomer(invoice.Id)">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      {{ invoice.TxnDate | date }} -
      {{ invoice.DocNumber }} - 
      {{ invoice.TotalAmt | currency }}
      {{ customerCache[invoice.Id].firstName }} {{ customerCache[invoice.Id].lastName }}
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>customers via http</span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customerCache">
      {{cust}}
    </li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: This works, but only barely.  The errors are still displayed, but the browser does not crash and the correct values are returned to the view.  Is there any way to call this function outside of a {{ }}?

Comment: use ng-init <a  ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" ng-init="getCustomer(invoice[data]["Id"][0])">

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I updated my answer with a complete runnable snippet. Hope this helps.

Comment: @cleftheris, thank you for your update.  I get the exact same errors and I suspect that I am somehow looping through the entire array of invoices for each invoice.  Once I figure out why this is the case, I will post an update.  However, you've proven that the problem is in my code.

Comment: @cleftheris, it took me a while to get it but I have it workly beautifully now.  Thank you for your help.  I'm going to keep playing around with it while learning more about Angular and hopefully understand it better. Thanks again.

Comment: This worked like a champ. I am still trying to understand why there is a need to cache the values returned.